# @JmsListener not working with @EnableAsync

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-jms

I am polling SQS in my spring boot application using jmsListener with CLIENT_Acknowledge session type and it is working fine, for errors i just throw an exception and JmsListener puts message back onto sqs. I added annotation with @Async and @EnableAsync(in config) the SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.class is catching the exception. I believe thats the reason why sqs message is not being sent to sqs in case of error. Please let me know if @Async annotation with @jmsListener annotation makes sense.

```
@Async
@JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name}")
public void listenEvent(@Headers Map<String, String> headers, @Payload String event) {
   //process event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Async` and `@JmsListener` do not make sense in combination.

The `@JmsListener` method already runs in its own thread.